# network requests being saved in memory?

Tags: ios, swift, caching

This has got to be one of the strangest thing I've come across...

Simple network request using alamofire

```
    manager.request(PostRouter.readPosts(pn: pn)).validate().responseJSON {
        response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let json):
            if let json = json as? JSON,
                let postsArray = json["posts"] as? [JSON],
                let posts = Post.build(from: postsArray) {
                completion(posts, nil)
            }
            else {
                completion(nil, NetworkingError.jsonParsingError)
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            completion(nil, error)
        }
    }
```

The same thing happens whether running from the simulator or mobile.

1. make request in airplane mode -> error of no internet connection.
2. make request again with internet -> loads posts
3. make request again in airplane mode -> loads posts without internet. Returns a success case with json value.

Even if in step 3 I make the request with an internet connection and have since modified the value of the data between steps 2 and 3, it will still return the exact same data from step 2 instead of fetching new data.  It's almost like the whole request, including the data is saved in memory.

The only way I can actually make a new request to fetch the new data is by removing it from my phone and installing it again.  The issue then repeats itself.

This happens to all the requests I make from the app.  Also, The issue isn't linked to Alamofire because without it the issue still occurs

Comment: Most likely related to `URLCache`

Comment: It's probably not an issue but a feature. Have you checked the response's cache headers?

Comment: i set the `cachePolicy` to `reloadIgnoringCacheData` but didn't make any difference.

Comment: @macmoonshine Fixed! Turns out I was setting the cache policy in the wrong place. I didn't know about caching with networking originally. I'm not sure why I didn't bump into this issue before. If you want to answer and i'll mark as correct.

Comment: I've added this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not an issue but a feature. Foundation will automatically cache responses. Check the response's cache headers (like `Expires`, `Cache-Control`, `ETag` etc.) if the server enables caching.

Comment: +1 My thoughts exactly. It's highly likely the endpoint has an Expires setting of something far in the future.